# How to interpolate a dataset and clamp at the ends?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a data set which can contain 1 to 4 points.

The data contains a pair of a float key and a value. the key ranges from [0,1].
My problem is that the first and the last data point do not necessarily lie on 0.0 and 1.0 respectively, they can lie anywhere, but the keys are sorted in ascending order (i.e. key at 0.1 comes before key at 0.2)

I want to interpolate the data given a variable `t` which also ranges within [0,1] which should give me the linear interpolated value between two keys.
If `t` is beyond a key, the value should be clamped.

For example:
if `key[0]` is `0.1` and `t` is `0.05`, it should return `key[0]`.

I fail to clamp the values aswell as combining it with a variable key amount.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct float_envelope{
    int point_count;
    float points[4];
    float values[4];
};

float clamp(float value, float min, float max) {
    if(value < min) {
        value = min;
    }
    if(value > max) {
        value = max;
    }
    return value;
}

float lerp(float a, float b, float t) {
  return (1 - t) * a + t * b;
}

float get_envelope_value(float_envelope env,float time) {
    float t = time;
    switch(env.point_count) {
        case 1:
            t = clamp(t,env.points[0],env.points[0]);
        break;
        case 2:
            t = clamp(t,env.points[0],env.points[1]);
        break;
        case 3:
            t = clamp(t,env.points[0],env.points[2]);
        break;
        default:
            t = clamp(t,env.points[0],env.points[3]);
        break;
    }
    float value = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < env.point_count-1; i++) {
        float a;
        float b;
        float value_a;
        float value_b;
        a = env.points[i];
        b = env.points[i+1];
        value_a = env.values[i];
        value_b = env.values[i+1];
        float length = b-a;
        t -= length;
        if(t <= 0) {
            float a = (-t / (length == 0.0 ? 1.0 : length));
            value = lerp(env.values[i],env.values[i+1],a);
        }
    }
    return value;
}

int main() {

    float_envelope env{3, {0.1f,0.5f,0.75f}, {1.0f,2.0f,7.0f}};
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.5f)); // should return 2.0f
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.75f)); // should return 7.0f
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,1.0f)); // should return 7.0f because the last key is at 0.75
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.0f)); // should return 1.0f because the first key is at 0.1
}
```

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j1v77va68)

the function `get_envelope_value`
subtracts all edges of the data set from `t` until it goes negative. this way i find the two points `t` lies between. The absolute of the negative value is the amount between these points.

Comment: Side note: [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> //std::clamp

struct float_envelope{
    int point_count;
    float points[4];
    float values[4];
};

float lerp(float a, float b, float t) {
  return (1 - t) * a + t * b;
}

float get_envelope_value(float_envelope env,float time) {
    const float t = std::clamp(time, env.points[0], env.points[env.point_count-1]);

    // find index of the lower and upper values    
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = env.point_count-1;
    for(int i = 1; i < env.point_count-1; i++)
    {
        const float pt = env.points[i];
        if(t >= pt)
            lower = i;
        if(t <= pt)
        {
            upper = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // interpolate the values
    if(upper == lower) return env.values[lower];
    const float fact = (t - env.points[lower]) / (env.points[upper] - env.points[lower]);
    return lerp(env.values[lower], env.values[upper], fact);
}

int main() {

    float_envelope env{3, {0.1f,0.5f,0.75f}, {1.0f,2.0f,7.0f}};
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.3f)); // should return 1.5f
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.5f)); // should return 2.0f
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.75f)); // should return 7.0f
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,1.0f)); // should return 7.0f because the last key is at 0.75
    std::printf("%0.2f\n",get_envelope_value(env,0.0f)); // should return 1.0f because the first key is at 0.1
}
```